# Find a particular solution for second order ODEs using undetermined coefficients method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Match the appropriate form of the particular solution labelled A through J with the differential equations below. Enter K if all of the particular solutions are incorrect.

$$y''-5y'-24y = 3xe^{2x}, (1)$$ 
$$y''-4y'+4y = -3xe^{2x}, (2)$$

$$y''-2y' = -8e^{2x}, (3)$$

$$y''-25y = -3x^3e^{2x}, (4)$$

$A. y_p = Ae^{2x}$

$B. y_p = Axe^{2x}$

$C. y_p = (Ax+B)e^{2x}$

$D. y_p = Ax^2e^{2x}$

$E. y_p = (Ax^2+Bx)e^{2x}$

$F. y_p = (Ax^2+Bx+C)e^{2x}$

$G. y_p = Ax^3e^{2x}$

$H. y_p = (Ax^3+Bx^2)e^{2x}$

$I. y_p = (Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx)e^{2x}$

$J. y_p = (Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D)e^{2x}$

K. None of the above

I chose C for (1), G for (2), B for (3) and J for (4). But none of them are correct, can anyone help me here?

Comment: Are you sure 2 isn't H (this is the form, but one of the constants will be zero and this reduces to G, but the form you would have picked is H)? Maybe I am reading the problem incorrectly and it is asking for what $y_p$ actually is. I agree with the other three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_ny^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+\cdots+a_1y'+a_0y=Q(x)$ wherein $a_n\ne 0$ and $Q(x)\ne 0$ in an interval, say $I$. Let we take $y_c(x)$ as the general solution of the related homogeneous equation: $$a_ny^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+\cdots+a_1y'+a_0y=0$$. Now if no term of $Q(x)$ is the same as a term in $y_c(x)$ then, $y_p(x)$ is constructed by a linear combination of all terms of $Q(x)$ and all its linearly independent derivatives. This means that if we have, for example $y_c(x)=C_1e^{ax}+C_2e^{bx}$ and $Q(x)=x^{t}e^{dx}$ such that $$a\ne b\neq d\ne a$$ then $$y_p(x)=A_tx^te^{dx}+A_{t-1}x^{t-1}+\cdots A_1xe^{dx}e^{dx}+A_0e^{dx}$$ It seems that for $4$ we can count on $J$.

Comment: Very nice, dear friend! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for your support. :)